# Recursive binding to object by from body attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Is it possible to bind post request which is as below :

```
{
    "name": "Tree Node 1",
    "children": 
    {
        "name": "Tree Node 2",
        "children": 
        {
            "name": "Tree Node 3",
            "children": [],
            "data": 
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

by using [From Body] attribute or it works only with simple request without "inheritance"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off is `children` an array or object? You use both.

I'd say it probably should be an array, so something like:

```
{
    "name": "Tree Node 1",
    "children": 
    [{
        "name": "Tree Node 2",
        "children": 
        [{
            "name": "Tree Node 3",
            "children": [],
            "data": 
            {
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

Then you just make a model that references itself:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TreeNode> Children { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

You didn't put anything in the `data` object so I can't guess what its structure is. Here I used a `Dictionary<string, string>` to make it so it can contain any key-value pairs.

Now just make your controller action like:

```
[HttpPost("test")]
public IActionResult Test([FromBody] TreeNode model)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> Children{get;set;}
    public Data Data {get;set;}
}
public class Data
{
    //properties of data
}
```